# Why is $\sinh$ often pronounced "shine"?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, terminology, hyperbolic-functions, pronunciation

I talked to some guys from the UK and they told me that they would pronounce $\sinh$ as "shine". I am not a native English speaker so I don't know, but in my country we call this function "sintsh" with a $sh$ as in "sharp" and a $s$ as in "saw". This seems to be the natural thing to do if you have not a clue how to call this function. Despite, in my country people try to avoid giving this function a name because they are afraid of making a fool out of themselves.

My question is:

> What is the standard name for this function and where does this "shine" come from?

Comment: Its pronounced sinh (Mathematicians make terrible linguists). P.S its full name is hyperbolic sine.

Comment: Well, if you want to reduce communication problems, call it "hyperbolic sine" with your UK buddies!

Comment: @Zach466920 That's not a pronunciation, that's a spelling.

Comment: The only pronunciation that I’ve heard is [sɪnt∫] (sintsh); I’m in the U.S.

Comment: In my experience in the US, I've heard both "shine" (as well as the always amusing co-shine) and "sintch". I think a Russian professor of mine was partial to "shine", although "sintch" is more common.

Comment: It's "sine' with an "h". Where does the $t$ come from in "sintch?" :)

Comment: $\tanh$ is pronounced "than" with an unvoiced "th" where I'm from. And $\cosh$ is just "cosh", not "coshine".

Comment: We call it "sinch" in my neck of the woods.  East Coast Megalopolis.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews duh, I was making a joke. You skip the rest of my comment? (P.S the only thing we can do on this site here is spell)

Comment: 'Shine' is easier to say than 'sinsh' I reckon. I've heard that some people say 'than' for tanh, but with the 'th' unvoiced like in 'think'

Comment: @Zach466920 It didn't read like a joke to me, and I'm a native-speaking user of English. Maybe because I expect a joke to be funny. If you were writing in a language foreign to you, would this "joke" be helpful, or confusing?

Comment: Eddie Izzard on American versus English English https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz4Ps55Rx40

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I note that mathematicians don't generally think before making abbreviations then proceed to give him the correct name of the function. I'd find this helpful indeed.

Comment: It's "see-unch" in redneck country.

Comment: @zhw. they do math out there? Maybe to getty up for some hyperbolic square dancing? ;)

Comment: @Zach466920 you said nothing about abbreviations. Is a non-English-speaker all to infer that, really? Especially when you start with a "joke" that is hard for a non-English speaker to infer is a joke?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sinh is obviously the abbreviation, plus I reaffirm that in the next sentence of my comment. You are a n sample size of 1. 1 dislike 2 likes is not enough data to draw conclusions. If Op has a problem I haven't heard anything. Let's just agree to disagree...

Comment: @Zach466920 Again, obvious to whom? It wasn't to me, and I speak English. Look, I like getting laughs. I play comic characters on stage. The biggest laugh I've ever gotten was at a company meeting, in an ad lib that interrupted a person's speech. I'm still proud of that joke, but I also always remember the look on the poor guy's face, because he hadn't heard what I said, and the room had erupted into laughter in the middle of his speech. There's a time and a place. In written response to an admitted English novice, asking for help, there is no reason to be obtuse.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since this question is about pronunciation of $\sinh$, or the hyperbolic sine, I thought it might be useful to see what the authoritative [Oxford English Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary) had to say:

[image]

This reveals that there are actually *three* pronunciations often encountered. From left to right:

- sh-eye-n $\qquad$ (i.e., **shine**)
- s-i-n-t-sh $\qquad$ (i.e., **cinch**)
- s-eye-n-ay-tch $\qquad$ (i.e., **sine H**)

I personally was unaware of the third pronunciation, but it seems your question regards the first pronunciation while the one mentioned by Brian M. Scott (and the one I've heard most often myself...maybe it has to do with being in the US or something) has to do with the second one.

Comment: Note that /t∫/ is the "ch" sound, as in *China*. So we have the pronunciations *shine*, *cinch*, *sine H*.

Comment: I like the third one. I think it should be written as sine h though, much easier to see.

Comment: @MagicMan: kudos to you for citing a good reference!

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks! Figured I'd use my school database subscription whilst still a student ;) haha.

Comment: I thought it would be pronounced sine -huh (just breathe out creepily at the end).

Comment: @Ilham Your comment made me laugh. :)

Comment: @Rahul Yes, I just added those pronunciations on the side of the bullet points for extra clarification. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

(Due to the nature of this question I've created a tongue-in-cheek response)

I never short cut the pronunciation of my trig functions.

Sine becomes Sin, Sine is most certainly not sinful.
Cos becomes Cos, Tangent becomes tan, secant becomes sec

Cosecant becomes csc!!! (that should be the real question here)

To answer your question, your typical dictionary has pronunciation guides for all the above trig functions, and generally speaking I prefer to just take the extra 1/10 of a second to eliminate ambiguity and just say hyperbolic sine. But, if you insist, these other pronunciations will suffice, just avoid csc!

P.S. I add h sin, h cos, and h tan, etc. to the list of possible pronunciations.

Comment: You can say the word "hyperbolic" in 1/10th of a second? That might cause more confusion than it eliminates!

Comment: Too bad! I loved the lounge in your cheek! :o)

Comment: @Bernard: A lounge in cheek sounds even more impressive than saying hyperbolic in tenth of a second.